# Taking this, and making that

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I had no idea how to word the title.

I need to take an output such as:

```
[~]# cat file
user1
domain1.com
user2
domain2.com
user3
domain3.com
```

and turn it into an output such as:

```
user1 domain1.com
user2 domain2.com
user3 domain3.com
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will probably get moved over to Stack Overflow, and then closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513861/bash-format-a-textfile-pair-every-two-lines. I had to strongly resist the urge to simply copy and paste the accepted answer over there to this thread, just for the potential rep points, but that would be cheating, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, I would have answered using `sed`, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read user
do 
        read domain
        echo $user $domain     
done
```

usage:

```
cat file | scriptname
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with some array-age

```
for i in `seq 1 2 ${#array[@]}` ; do echo "${array[$i]} ${array[$i + 1]}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, there's gotta be an easy way to do this.  I clearly haven't got enough sleep, because I can't think of any.  But, because I don't like arrays, I used a for loop.  It essentially goes through each LINE, and outputs the even numbers to a new file without a linebreak, and appends the odd ones with a break.  Seems to work!

```
COUNT=0
for LINE in $(cat file.txt);do
  if [ $(($COUNT % 2)) -eq 0 ];then 
      echo -n $LINE >> newfile.txt
      echo -n " " >> newfile.txt
  else
      echo $LINE >> newfile.txt
  fi
COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
done
```

--Christopher Karel